# Whether to use Conditionnel Présent or Passé in this particular sentence?

Tags: temps-grammatical

In conversation with my colleague, I said jokingly:

> On le soupçonne d’être mêlé à une affaire très douteuse, et pour cause. Ça m’en a tout l’air.
>
> On **voudrait** blanchir de l'argent qu'on ne s'y **prendrait** pas autrement.
>
> {or}: On **aurait voulu** blanchir de l'argent qu'on ne s'y **serait** pas **pris** autrement.

I went with the present conditional, but now I wonder in hindsight how the version with the past conditional differs in meaning?

What we're talking about here is a *general* hypothetical condition that could apply to anyone and anytime, so is it better to stick with the present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *conditionnel passé* can be used to express regret, meaning it is too late now to do the refered action. Therefore,

> On **voudrait** blanchir de l'argent qu'on ne s'y **prendrait** pas autrement.

refer to an action we could do today and its outcome, while :

> On **aurait voulu** blanchir de l'argent qu'on ne s'y **serait** pas **pris** autrement.

refer to the action in the past that we cannot change.

I believe the difference between *conditionnel présent* and *conditionnel passé* is similar to the difference between *past tense* and *present continuous* in a way. For example :

> I never **went** to the museum.

means that I don't intend to go in the future, while

> I have never been to the museum.

implies I have not been **yet** but it is a possibility for me.

I found more information [here](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/conjugaison/conditionnel-passe-48.php).

[Here](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-20173.php) is an exercise for you if you'd like.

Comment: Hi. I don't think this is about expressing regret, though it may indeed be interpreted that way in a *normal* past conditional. Here, even in the past conditional, the idea of "exactement / yeah, that's the way to go" is implied: "***Exactement !*** On aurait voulu blanchir de l'argent qu'on ne s'y serait pas pris autrement."

Comment: I'm not talking about the *general, basic* comparison between the present conditional and the past conditional, but rather the difference perceived with this rather *unique* conditional construction.

Comment: It's true that in this particular case, the sentence does not express regret. Still, in the first version you are talking about something that could be happening right now. In the second version, you are talking about something could have happened in the past, but we are past it (in a way) and cannot go back.